# Is there a v-cloak inverse?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

According to [VueJS documentation](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#v-cloak), `v-cloak` "directive can be used to hide un-compiled mustache bindings until the Vue instance is ready.". In other word, I can hide a `div` or something like that, and it will be displayed when vue is ready.

Does VueJS provides its inverse? Something that hides *until* VueJS is ready?

Comment: Did you mean something that will be displayed until the instance is compiled?

Comment: @Vivick Yes! Exactly.

Comment: Just hide the element in your CSS, and make it visible in the `created` or `mounted` lifecycle hooks?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

As simple as:

```
<div v-if="false">Will be visible until vue is mounted/ready...</div>
```

Work for all versions.

The element has to be inside your container... if you use to hide your master container, change it that way:

```
<div id="app">
    <div v-if="false">Visible while loading...</div>
    <div v-cloak>Visible when ready...</div>
</div>
```

Comment: I wish all the answers will be like this! very simple, nice and elegant solution

Comment: Thanks for sharing this awesome solution!

Answer (score 4):

There plenty of solutions, I think another one will be to use `v-if` with a false property in `data` like:

```
<div v-if="false">Loading Vue....</div>
<div v-cloak>vue loaded</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's what I did which doesn't require the "inverse" to be inside the app

```
<div id="app" v-cloak>...</div>
<div id="cloak-alt">  <!-- must be directly after your v-cloak element -->
  Loading Page etc
</div>
```

```
[v-cloak] {
  display: none;
}

#cloak-alt {
  display: none;
}

[v-cloak] + #cloak-alt {
  /* As long as this is visible, display can be whatever */
  display: block;
}
```

This is the best way IMO to hide the entire page while Vue loads.  The `v-if="false"` feels a tad hacky to me but work for hiding some components inside your app; although, you could use the same approach with a different css selector to accomplish the same thing