# Vue 3 - show loader until all child components are loaded

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3

I'm having trouble displaying Vue Loader Component while waiting for other components to load.

```
<div id="app">
    <loader v-if="!componentsReady"></loader>
    <some-page v-else></some-page>
</div>
```

`<Loader>` isn't displayed since it itself is a vue component.(based on logic it's waiting for all child components to load)

**app.js**

Here I want to display **Loader** component, and wait until **SomePage** component and it's child components are loaded.

On **mounted** I'm setting that components are ready, but this way I also won't get **Loader** component displayed, event it's not async.

```
import Loader from "./Loader";

const app = createApp({
    data() {
        return {
            componentsReady: false
        }
    },
    components: {
        SomePage: defineAsyncComponent(() => import('./somePage')),
        Loader
    },
    mounted() {
        this.$nextTick(() => {
            this.componentsReady = true;
        });
    }
});

app.mount('#app');
```

Comment: Seems to me that the problem is, that you set `componentsReady=true` in the `mounted()` hook of your `app` instead of the ones in Component.

Answer (score 3):

In vue3 you have a Suspense component that might help cf. https://v3-migration.vuejs.org/breaking-changes/suspense.html

But I think that what you are looking for is more like the v-cloak directive cf. https://v3.vuejs.org/api/directives.html#v-cloak

Comment: I've found Suspence but it says that it shouldn't be in the production. Will try if v-cloak works. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Faced the same problem and think we need **opposite of v-cloak**.

```
<div v-if="false">Loading Vue....</div>
```

I know this is late but adding for people who may need a solution like me.

Got it from this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46682000/is-there-a-v-cloak-inverse).